# Who has right of way between a legal u-turn vs car driving out of a parking lot as per Texas rules?

Tags: united-states, traffic, texas

A car stopped in a left-only lane (not a traffic signal/intersection) on a main street and was making a u-turn (it is not prohibited) and no-through traffic from the opposite side. The car turns and has reached half-way at an angle into the third-lane (4-lane each way). At same time, a driver coming out of a parking lot takes a right and tried to move to the same lane and not the right-most(closest to curb) and meets this above car in an accident.

Since the car in the left-turn lane is on a main road, do they have right-of-way over the parking lot car. The first car turned into the lanes even before the other car drove out of the parking lot. Is there a law about who takes precedence in this case?

Answer (score 3):

No party is granted the right of way, instead, some party is required to *yield* the right of way. [Sec. 545.155 of the Texas Transportation Code](https://texas.public.law/statutes/tex._transp._code_section_545.155) says

> An operator about to enter or cross a highway from an alley, building,
>   or private road or driveway shall yield the right-of-way to a vehicle
>   approaching on the highway to be entered.

[Sec. 545.256](https://texas.public.law/statutes/tex._transp._code_section_545.256) likewise requires that

> An operator emerging from an alley, driveway, or building in a
>   business or residence district shall:
>
> (1) stop the vehicle before moving on a sidewalk or the sidewalk area
>   extending across an alley or driveway;
>
> (2) yield the right-of-way to a pedestrian to avoid collision; and
>
> (3) on entering the roadway, yield the right-of-way to an approaching
>   vehicle.

[The law against wide right turns](https://texas.public.law/statutes/tex._transp._code_section_545.101) says "To make a right turn at an intersection, an operator shall make both the approach and the turn as closely as practicable to the right-hand curb or edge of the roadway"; [intersection](https://texas.public.law/statutes/tex._transp._code_section_541.303) "means the common area at the junction of two highways, other than the junction of an alley and a highway", and [highway or street](https://texas.public.law/statutes/tex._transp._code_section_541.302) "means the width between the boundary lines of a publicly maintained way any part of which is open to the public for vehicular travel", i.e. the part where the parking lot empties into the main road.

Comment: "No party is granted the right of way, instead, some party is required to yield the right of way"  To-may-toe, to-ma-toe.  By defining who must yield, you implicitly define who has the right of way.   "An operator about to enter or cross a highway from an alley, building, or private road or driveway shall yield the right-of-way to a vehicle approaching on the highway to be entered."  Would a vehicle making a U-turn already be in the highway, and thus the parked car must yield to it?

Comment: @Andy: If the laws of human governments would require vehicle X to yield the right of way to vehicle Y, but the laws of Sir Isaac Newton would forbid it from doing so, vehicle Y does not have the right of way.  If a driver of Y can see that X is not yielding the right of way, Y would have a duty to avoid hitting X, independent of any duty X might have to yield the right of way.